# Issue while trying to add starting from first non-zero value of DataFrame. There are records with zero values in middle of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe df. I need to add value 10 starting from non-zero values in dataframe and keep the zeros before non-zero value as it is. I am using following code

```
    df_lci = df.replace ({0: np.nan}).add(10).fillna(0)
```

Problem is I am having zero values in middle of the column. 10 is not being added zero values which is present in middle of the column. Please help solving the issue

Dataframe `df`

```
    value
1   0
2   0
3   0 
4   0
5   51.134
6   52.4833
7   53.7698
8   0
9   4
```

Expected output:

```
   0
   0
   0 
   0
   61.134
   62.4833
   63.7698
   10
   14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.loc[df.value.ne(0).idxmax():,'value']+=10
df
Out[579]: 
     value
1   0.0000
2   0.0000
3   0.0000
4   0.0000
5  61.1340
6  62.4833
7  63.7698
8  10.0000
9  14.0000
```

Comment: Hi Wen, I am getting an error message : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: @ArvinthKumar that is dataframe or Series ? you mentioned that is dataframe with columns name 'value'

Comment: Hi Wen, It is a series. Sorry i did not notice

Comment: @ArvinthKumar then `df.loc[df.ne(0).idxmax():]+=10
`